# Setting User-Agent String for site via web.config

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

I am not sure if I asked the question in right way. But here is the scenario -

In a website we use Infragistic's controls. Which loads fine on ie9 but when we open the site in ie11 then the controls is not visible but just a text **Table Control**.

Below is an image -

[image]

I did some research and found out if I change the **user agent string** to Internet Explorer 9 on Developer's tool window then it loads the controls as expected.

Below is how it looks after changing the user agent string - 
[image]

This is the setting -

[image]

Is there a way to change this user agent string somehow without a code change ? like setting on web.config ?

Thanks in advance. 
Rohit

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. The right question is _"How can I let ASP.NET detect IE 11 as a browser with full capabilities?"_. See for example [IE10 and IE11 and Windows 8.1 and __doPostBack](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IE10AndIE11AndWindows81AndDoPostBack.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I just did not know how to ask this.. should I update the question with the heading given by you

Comment: If you take the suggestion from the link that @CodeCaster provided, you may need to use the Version Utility on your web site project unless you want to change the Infragistics assembly references by hand.